# Format the global log output using captains-log

Tags: sails.js

I'd like the SailsJS logger to output the date that the log was emitted as well as some context state data (if available).

I'm considering using the *log.config* like this

```
module.exports.log = {
  custom: customLogger,

  // Disable captain's log so it doesn't prefix or stringify our meta data.
  inspect: false
};
```

Where `customLogger` is a logger that I know I can configure to display dates.

However, my question is if there's an easier way to configure the default Sails logger, `captains-log`, to display dates on all output.

Also, it would be useful if I could define certain data to be displayed with a log, like, if there's a request context, to display the request URI, or if the error was thrown from a helper, to display a stringyfied output of the `input` or `output`.